# Distance between orthonormal basis and standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-mathematics

Let $\{\vec{a}_1,\dots,\vec{a}_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\vec{a}_i=[a_{i1},\dots,a_{in}]$. Let $S_i=\{\text{all } k \text{ such that } |a_{ik}|\geq|a_{il}|\text{ for all }1\leq l\leq n\}$. That is, $S_i\subset\{1,\dots,n\} $ contains the index of the entries of $\vec{a}_i$ that has the biggest absolute value. Note that each $S_i$ can have more than one element.

Prove that we can select one element from each $S_i$, such that the set of elements we select is precisely $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Intuitively this is clear, as $S_i$ contains the index of the axis that $\vec{a}_i$ is closest to, and as $\{\vec{a}_1,\dots,\vec{a}_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis we should be able to find an order of axis such that each $a_{i}$ is closest to a different axis. But how can we prove it precisely?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I've got the question right, but are the 3 vectors $(1/\sqrt{2},1/2,1/2)$, $(1/\sqrt{2},-1/2,-1/2)$ and $(0,1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})$ a counter-example?

Comment: @Peter You are correct! My intuition is just false...